# Internet recovery mode: Always restart after download complete

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, recovery, internet-recovery

Please help :(. I have a problem with my macbook pro md101 2012 when i work with it then my mac is suddenly die by itself. When i turn it on it show a kernel panic, and when i log in it just stuck in apple logo with progress bar then restart again, i tried everything like clear nvram, get into safe mode, get into recovery mode, and internet recovery mode but no luck, it just suddenly restart when loading progress. Now my hard drive has been formatted, and im trying to get into internet recovery mode but same result. Is there a problem with the harddrive?

Answer (score 1):

I had MBP 2012 mid and it showed a similar pattern (infinite rebooting). I took it to the Apple service center and the source of the problem was in the mainboard. I suggest take it to the Apple service center.